# How do I change the title font size of a block in LaTex beamer?

Tags: beamer, fonts, spacing

I have been using `scriptsize` to have my text uniformly the same size, but it seems to be skipping tha block titles.

```tex
\begin{scriptsize}
 \frametitle{Extension and Research Question}
 \begin{block} {Research Question}
  How does LaTeX provide extra tools in an academic setting
 \end{block}
\end{scriptsize}
```

I have tried adding the `\begin{scriptsize}` and `\end{scriptsize}` closer to the title but no results from there.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue.   See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that .

Comment: Try `\setbeamerfont{block title}{size=\scriptsize}`.